# How to define an contains using firebase-bolt?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase-bolt to set my rules.

My bolt:

```
// ######## CONTENTS
path /contents {
  read() = true;
  index() = ["dt_created"];
}

path /contents/$id is Timestamped<Contents> {
  write() = isSignedIn() && isAllowEdit(this);
}

type Contents {
    text : String, 
    address : String,
    organization: String | Null,
    location: String | Null,
    map_lat : String, 
    map_lng : String, 
    num_favorite: Number,
    num_comment: Number, 
    num_denounce: Number, 
    removed: Boolean, 
    category_id : String, 
    user_id : String,
    photos: String[]
}

//
// Helper Functions
//
isSignedIn() = auth != null;
isAllowEdit(value) = (prior(value) == null || newData.child('user_id').val() == auth.uid);
```

I would like the only the owner the post can edit, but anyone can update the counters.

I think :

```
"contents": {
  "$id": {
    "num_favorite": {
      ".write": true
    ....
```

Not sure if it's possible. But can I create rules to edit only field with contains ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in regular Firebase Security Rules:

```
"contents": {
  "$id": {
    "num_favorite": {
      ".write": true
    }
```

Translates to this on Bolt:

```
path /contents/$id/num_favorite {
  write() = true;
}
```

This will work, because you're *adding* a new permission and not trying to *remove* an existing permission (which is [not possible in Firebase's security rules language](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade)).

But I would consider separating the vote out into its own higher-level node:

```
path /favorite_counts/$id {
  write() = true;
}
```

This keeps your security rules simpler and more isolated from each other.